# Can I reduce volume of person in conference call on Skype?

Tags: skype, voice, conferencing

Is is possible to reduce the volume of a person on conference call who is sitting next to me? It is really annoying when we use headphones.

Comment: I don't use Skype, but I've used a lot of difference conference call softwares and there is usually a way to mute people, and so I usually mute anyone in the same room.

Comment: No it is not possible, but Google+ Hangout has such features with Hangout Toolbox application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not currently offered within skype.